# Power BI - load *.htm file saved as .xls

Tags: powerbi

I have a requirement where I have to import an *.xls* file which is saved as **.*htm, .*html**

Opening the file and clicking on saving as, will usually show the format that the file is in and this is how it looks -

[image: File Format]

[image: File]

I clicked on Binary and it showed me the .xls file and I opened it as *Excel workbook, csv, text, html, xml* but it didn't work :-

Opening it as Excel Workbook gives me this error - **Eternal Table is not in the Expected Format.**

How do we load this inside Power BI. The data is present in Sheet1 starting from Row Number 5. I have been struggling with this by trying to load it.

I can't edit and re-save the file manually as .xlsx, as it cannot be automated. 
Also to note, saved it as a .xlsx file and it works fine. But that's not what I need.

Kindly help me with this.

I did refer to this article - but I am not familiar with M query

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c58f8b19-b2d6-4ef6-890b-f10c62c0096f/external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format?forum=powerquery

Other Similar Question - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29064908/HTML-Excel-file-Power-Query-BI-Connection-can-this-be-done.html

This is how My M-Code looks like,

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("\\serverA\ShareB$\Desktop"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xls")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", let latest = List.Max(#"Filtered Rows"[Date created]) in each [Date created] = latest),
    #"\\serverA\ShareB$\Desktop\_Raw Data Dump 2018-Oct-4 6-00-53 AM xls" = #"Filtered Rows1"{[#"Folder Path"="\\serverA\ShareB$\Desktop\",Name="Raw Data Dump 2018-Oct-4 6-00-53 AM.xls"]}[Content]
in
    #"\\ServerA\ShareB$\Desktop\_Raw Data Dump 2018-Oct-4 6-00-53 AM xls"
```

Adding a sample file here for reference on the file type -

> https://www.glump.net/_media/howto/web/serve-html-as-an-excel-file-from-a-web-application/example-html.xls.zip
>
> I tried with the above file on the link and it produces the same
>   error. So, the question here is how to load the file in the above link
>   inside Power BI, without changing the file manually.

Comment: What does your M code look like when you load this? (You can find the code under Advanced Editor).

Comment: @AlexisOlson updated the question with M code. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by and .xls saved as an .html. Is there an example file you can share?

Comment: @AlexisOlson It's a confidential file and can't really share it. But, the one thing that I believe it has .html in it is, when I open the file manually and click on save as - "it gives me the attached screenshot", over there you could see Webpage type. This as much as I know, will always show the actual format of the file.If I change that to .xlsx and save it and open it, then it works again.

Comment: @AlexisOlson added a screenshot of the file (sample values)

Comment: Can you strip the file of any confidential or superfluous information and share that? I don't think I can help unless I can replicate the error and I haven't managed to do that playing with my own xls files.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I understand. I went on to find a similar file online - This is my file type - https://www.glump.net/_media/howto/web/serve-html-as-an-excel-file-from-a-web-application/example-html.xls.zip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181299/discussion-between-sid29-and-alexis-olson).

Comment: @AlexisOlson The link to the extended question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664525/power-bi-load-htm-file-saved-as-xls-starting-from-row-number-5 Please help me solving this. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sample file you linked, I was able to load the file using `Web.Page` rather than `Excel.Workboook` and then clicking on the table shown below:

[image: Query Editor]

My full query looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\aolson\Downloads\example-html.xls"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xls")),
    #"C:\Users\aolson\Downloads\example-html xls\_example-html xls" = #"Filtered Rows"{[#"Folder Path"="C:\Users\aolson\Downloads\example-html.xls\",Name="example-html.xls"]}[Content],
    #"Imported Excel" = Web.Page(#"C:\Users\aolson\Downloads\example-html xls\_example-html xls"){0}[Data]
in
    #"Imported Excel"
```

Note: Clicking on the table indicated above is equivalent to selecting the cell value in the `Data` column and row 0, hence `{0}[Data]`.

Comment: This works only if the first row starts from line number 1 and it doesn't work if it starts from line number 5 or 6...Please help me with that one. I am accepting this answer because my question wasn't very clear and you have answered the requirements. I will open that as a new question.

Comment: You just need to filter the table until you have only have the single row you want or else use a different row reference instead of `{0}`, but yes, feel free to post that question separately if you need further clarification on that part.

Comment: Yes posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664525/power-bi-load-htm-file-saved-as-xls-starting-from-row-number-5

Comment: That's the thing, it is not showing the data required for me to filter it. The reference isn't available. Just source = Service is present and source = table is not present at all.

Comment: I see what you mean now. If I figure it out, I'll answer the other question.

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciate it.